# PayPal: Instrument declined when in live mode using API

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

We're currently using the rest API for PayPal (PHP) and everything was working fine in the sandbox. When we went live we continue to get the following message:

```
{"name":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","details":[],"message":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","debug_id":"8ad80896530bd"}
```

What does this mean and more importantly is there a reason this is not being caught as an exception in the php SDK. It seems to pass through without issues (using the exact same code as in the sample file for executing a payment). Is there a way to catch this?

Comment: the message returned seems clear to me,. di you read the page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INSTRUMENT_DECLINED

Comment: Yup. Read that. was hoping maybe it was a setting we could change to fix it (like accepting card payments or something but we've tried all those). More concerned on how to reliably catch the exception.

Comment: that would be a business process not a coding one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like the payment method was turned down by the bank, or is not allowed for the attempted purchase. For instance prepaid debit cards are often now able to complete certain payments, and many cards are restricted geographically.

> everything was working fine in the sandbox

The sandbox doesn't actually check with the bank whether a card is good, so it wouldn't have thrown the same error. The sandbox is for testing whether the code paths work as intended. The problem is not with your script.

Comment: so the error is exactly what the error syas it was, amazing :-)

Comment: @Dagon  :-)  Sometimes all it takes is a paraphrase to make things click. Happens to me all the time

Comment: BeetleJuice BeetleJuice BeetleJuice .. waiting

Comment: Yeah, I know :) -  I was more concerned as to why it was not being caught as an exception by the sdk. If it's not an exception how should this be dealt with?

Answer (score 2):

In case other people look at this issue.

There is actually an official explanation and solution in the paypal documentation.

> A buyer's funding source can fail for several reasons, including:
>
> The billing address associated with the financial instrument could not
> be confirmed. The transaction exceeds the card limit. The card issuer
> denied the transaction. If a funding source fails, the Orders API
> returns the INSTRUMENT_DECLINED error. Handle this error and provide
> the buyer an opportunity to select a different payment option by
> restarting the payment in the onApprove function.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/add-capabilities/handle-funding-failures/